# C++ move semantics and built-in types

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am trying to understand move semantics using the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
   public:
   int a;
   A():a{1}{}
   A(A&& rref):a{rref.a}{cout<<"move constructor called"<<endl;}
   A(const A& ref):a{ref.a}{cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;}
};

int main(){

  A original; // original object

  cout<<"original.a = "<<original.a<< "|  address original.a="<< &(original.a)<<endl;

  A movedto (std::move(original)); // calls A(A&&)

  cout<<"original.a = "<<original.a<< "| address original.a"<< &(original.a)<<endl;
  cout<<"movedto.a = "<<movedto.a<<"| address movedto.a"<< &(movedto.a)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Which give the following output

```
original.a = 1|  address original.a=0x7fff1611b6d0
move constructor called
original.a = 1| address original.a0x7fff1611b6d0
movedto.a = 1| address movedto.a0x7fff1611b6e0
```

As it can be seen, the address of `original.a` and `movedto.a` are different, hence the member `a` underwent a copy operation in `A(A&& rref):a{rref.a}`.

I am aware that *move* degrades to *copy* for built-in types. My question is that **what do I do if I want to hijack (not copy) an instance of the class such as this one**. Assume that I have 100 members (instead of just one) of built-in type, making copy expensive.

One obvious way would be to store the object on the heap and use reference semantics to pass it around. But would like to stay with value semantics and still be able to circumvent the copying.

Comment: Copying 100 `int`s is still not expensive. But you could use a `std::vector<int>` member and move that. It will handle everything for you.

Comment: Two questions:  1)  Does `std::vector<T>` behave with value semantics?  2)  If the answer to 1 is yes, what does `vector<T>` do?

Comment: `a{rref.a}` should be `a{std::move(rref.a)}` to actually move `a` (although it will still copy as it is the same for an `int`).

Comment: Store a `unique_ptr` member pointing to a struct with your 100 members. It will give you cheap move, but slightly slower member access.

Comment: Dhruv:  I think @HowardHinnant's second question should be read as "how is `std::vector<T>` implemented to achieve this?"

Comment: The fact that you're using a built-in type here is irrelevant. It doesn't matter what type you make `a`, `original.a` and `movedto.a` will still have different addresses.

Comment: @NathanOliver, we do not need to add a call to `std::move()` because the result of member access operator `(.)` on an rvalue reference `rref` is also an rvalue. But yeah, that still does not matter as the move will degrade to copy in case of an `int`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: No, @NathanOliver is correct , `rref.a` is an lvalue because `rref` is an lvalue (named rvalue reference). You would need `std::move(rref.a)` if you want it to be an xvalue. Or, if you had done `std::move(rref).a`, then it would also work because then the `.` operator will provide an rvalue from an rvalue.

Comment: @Dhruv: When you move an object, what's really happening is that you're simply constructing a new object with the move constructor. It's still a different object, which means that, by definition, it has a different address. Try it with an object which very obviously has a move constructor, like `std::vector`. Create a vector A, fill it with objects, print its address. Create another vector B in the same scope, move constructed from A, and print its address. It will be different, guaranteed. For completeness, print A's address again after the move. It will be the same as it was before.

Comment: One small caveat to the statement I made above -- *"It's still a different object, which means that, by definition, it has a different address."* -- Different objects with non-overlapping lifetimes can have the same address. But in this case, we're move constructing one from another, so their lifetimes must overlap at least for the duration of the constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley its not `A`'s address that's remotely interesting in the move, what is interesting is its contents. So I'm going to ignore that portion of your comments.  `A`'s data isn't being `moved` because it can't be; the code is wrong but even if corrected its not movable data.  If its internals were movable and was coded properly they would be moved. If you move a vector, I would expect the address of its internal data storage / address of the elements of the vector to stay the same because you moved it instead of copying it. That's the whole POINT of the move, to avoid a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and/or doesn't make sense.

---

We start with:

```
A original; // original object
```

And the main part of the question is:

> What do I do if I want to hijack (not copy) an instance of the class
>   such as this one?

So that would mean that we end up with:

```
A movedto; // new object that has all of original's members
```

But the caveat here is that we want "to circumvent the copying" and we don't want to use references or pointers, i.e "reference semantics", only the "stack" or "value semantics".

If we want `movedto` to have the same members at the same memory locations that were already allocated then we can just create a reference to `original`:

```
A& movedto{original}; // references members at the same memory locations.
```

But part of this question states that we are not using references because presumably we want this object to have a different lifetime. So if we want to keep `original`'s members "alive" and allocated beyond the end of the current block then we immediately find that we are not in control of that underlying memory.

---

In this question `original` is an object with automatic storage durtion. Objects with automatic storage duration have their lifetimes managed automatically according to their scope. The compiler may have used a stack to store it and the compiler may use a stack pointer that gets moved downwards each time an object is added but the C++ standard doesn't specify how it should be done. We do know that the standard specifies that the objects with automatic storage duration will be destroyed in the reverse order they were created when the scope ends.

So trying to control where an object with automatic storage durtaion is created does not make sense and assigning the members of such an object to another doesn't make sense either. The memory is allocated automatically.

If we want to reuse the variables that were already allocated as part of an object with automatic storage duration (stack/value semantics) then we're using memory that will be deallocated when that object's lifetime ends. We must use dynamic storage for that (i.e. the "heap", or "reference semantics").

Comment: Both the approaches would use heap for storing the actual data and so on the top it looks like value semantics but internally we are exchanging the pointers to implement the move. This leads me believe the following. Please correct me if I am wrong.


1.  The data should always reside on the heap with a managing handle object (unique_ptr or Impl*) on which we implement the move constructor and assignment.

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, both are using dynamic storage duration (heap storage). And yes, I don't see a way to do this in memory allocated for an object with automatic storage durtation (stack). I've updated the answer to focus on the main gist of the question.

Comment: Got it. We've deviated from the topic of the question but I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks